# Basic Javascript if statement with Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

For some reason this if statement **never gets to the else**. When I click on #drawer-drop the margin changes but I can't ever change it back. I'm not seeing any console errerors.

```
#drawer{margin-top:-600px;}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#drawer-drop").click(function(){
    if($("#drawer").css('margin-top','-600px')){
       $('#drawer').css('margin-top','0px');
    }else{
       $('#drawer').css('margin-top','-600px');
    }
  });
});

<nav id="drawer">
  <h1>This will be a sweet menu.</h1>
</nav>

<a id="drawer-drop">MENU</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "mistake" - you put inside the `if` statement **Setter** `.css( propertyName, value )` (**Set** the value too...), instead of **Getter** `.css( propertyName )` (**Get** the value of...).

```
if($("#drawer").css('margin-top') == "-5px"){
  console.log("Do something");
}
```

- **Jquery CSS()** `get` docs: https://api.jquery.com/css/#css1
- **Related article:** https://riptutorial.com/jquery/example/11775/css---getters-and-setters

#### Basic Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#drawer-drop").click(function(){
    console.log($("#drawer").css('margin-top'));
    if($("#drawer").css('margin-top') == "-5px"){
      /* Setter */
      $('#drawer').css('margin-top','0px');
      $('#drawer').css('background','red');
    }else{
     /* Setter */
      $('#drawer').css('margin-top','-5px');
      $('#drawer').css('background','blue');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#drawer{
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<nav id="drawer">
  <h1>This will be a sweet menu.</h1>
</nav>

<a id="drawer-drop" href="#">MENU</a>
```